# Testing the launch of a module in a java ServerSocket?

Tags: java, sockets

I developed a Java ServerSocket that is always running and it executes many modules . My server start by execution a BatchScript file (start.bat). I want to test if the module is successfully executed and give the user w feedback on the cmd console(when i launch the server from eclipse i can see the long on eclipse console only) . I want to check my server statut after a periode of time knowing that it is always running .

Here is the implementation of my server  :

```
public Server() throws InterruptedException
{
    //this.es = e;
    try {
        sockserv= new ServerSocket(6020) ;

        System.out.println("Server Started");
        myModule mod= new myModule(); 
        mod.displayLogOnCmd();
                    mod.checkServerEveryPeriodOfTime();



    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    while(SERVER_STATUT)
    {
            try {
                Socket socket = sockserv.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

My Question :
How to display log info of eclipse in the Cmd ? and how to see if the server launched the module or not ??
Thank You :)

Comment: Incomprehensible. What's your question?

Comment: How to display log info of eclipse in the Cmd ? and how to see if the server launched the module or not ??

Comment: What does Eclipse have to do with it? Question remains incomprehensible.